# Why is my for loop only returning last value?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

```
for desc in database.desc:
    if sub in desc:
        station = desc.split(";")
        station.pop(0)
        station.pop(0)
        station.pop(1)
        if len(station) > 1:
            station.pop()
        print(station)
    else:
        ""

print(station)
```

The first print statement gives all the valeus I want. When I'm printing the statement oustide the for loop. It only gives me the last value of the csv file.

Comment: `station` is overwritten on each iteration of the loop, so once the loop ends, it’s value will be the last thing it was set to, which will be the last value assigned in the loop. If you want to keep all the values, use a list and append to it.

Answer (score 1):

Because in each iteration of your `for` loop you are assigning the value of `desc.split(";")` to `station` so it holds the current value at each moment, when the `for` loops ends then the value that it holds is the last one, and then that's when you print it.